# Gridsearch LGBM

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Не пойму в чем ошибка при построении модели, верней не знаю как исправить
[image: gridsearch]

[image: trace error]

Answer (score 1):

```
train_x.reshape(-1,1)
train_y.reshape(-1,1)
```